# Version control suffix on all files

Tags: javascript, html, css, version

In my index.html I have a number of scripts and css files that I have version control suffix on, like so:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/framework/compile/css/main.min.css?version=3.0">

  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/framework/compile/js/app.min.js?version=3.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/framework/compile/js/app.min.js?version=3.0"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I also have a directory of html views and smaller html files. Whenever I update one of these files, I increase the minor version number. For example, `/framework/compile/css/main.min.css?version=3.0` becomes `/framework/compile/css/main.min.css?version=3.1` after an update.

However, if I do a major site update and change most files, I will push the version number to `4.0`. I don't want to have to manually change the version number on every file. Is there an easy and readable way to do this with a javascript variable or something similar.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
    <script>var version = "3.0";</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/framework/compile/css/main.min.css?version=" + version>

  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/framework/compile/js/app.min.js?version=" + version></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/framework/compile/js/app.min.js?version=" + version></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The above is obviously incorrect syntax and does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fast solution, using some Jquery:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!--Your css and js will be referred inside this div -->
    <div id="updatable_source"></div>
    
    <!--Version updater script-->  
    <script>
      var version = '3.0'
      $('#updatable_source').html(
        '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"'
          +'href="/framework/compile/css/main.min.css?version='+version+'"/>'
        +'<script type="text/javascript" src="/framework/compile/js/app.min.js'
          +'version='+version+'"/>'
        +'<script type="text/javascript" src="/framework/compile/js/app.min.js version='+version+'"/>'
      );
    </script>  
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Just change the 'version' var for updating the version

Comment: Thanks but I'm not keen on installing the full jQuery library just for this, and it doesn't seem to address version control of CSS files in the head, or html view files in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Using Pure Javascript**

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
      Your main content should come BEFORE your javascript. 
      The script to include the files should be immediately after your content, 
      but before any other script file includes or in page javascript.
    </div>

    <script>

      /*******************************************************
      / Alternate Solution: If you're only wanting to get the
      / most current version of each file, you can just append
      / a datetime stamp to the script tag's url src
      /*******************************************************/

      //get current datetime in milliseconds
      var version = new Date().valueOf();

      /*******************************************************
      / OR you can use manual version numbers as per your ?
      /*******************************************************/

      //variable to hold version number
      var version = "3.0";

      /*******************************************************
      / Add the following ahead of any other scripts before
      / the closing body tag
      /*******************************************************/

      var cssLnk = document.createElement("link");
      cssLnk.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
      cssLnk.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
      cssLnk.setAttribute("href", "/framework/compile/css/main.min.css?version=" + version);

      document.head.appendChild(cssLnk);

      var scr_A = document.createElement("script");
      scr_A.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
      scr_A.setAttribute("src", "/framework/compile/js/app.min.js?version=" + version);

      document.body.appendChild(scr_A);

      var scr_B = document.createElement("script");
      scr_B.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
      scr_B.setAttribute("src", "/framework/compile/js/app.min.js?version=" + version);

      document.body.appendChild(scr_B);

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```